# Seeding large lookup table data with Entity Framework Code First migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm about to start a new project and I'd like to use Entity Framework Code First migrations; i.e., write the database in code and have it all auto-generated for me and the schema updated etc.

However, my stumbling block is that I have one lookup table which I need to import and has over 2 million records (it's a post code lookup table).

My question is, how do you deal with such large pre-populated lookup tables within Entity Framework Code First migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration doesn't actually have to drop/recreate the whole table (and won't unless you specify that it should).  Normally, the migrations just do the Up/Down methods to alter the table with additional columns, etc.

Do you actually need to drop the table? If so, do you really need to seed it from EF? The EF cost for doing 2 million inserts will be astounding, so if you could do it as a manual step with something more efficient (that will use bulk inserts), it would be very much preferred.

If I had to do that many inserts, I would probably break it out into SQL files and do something like what's mentioned here: [EF 5 Code First Migration Bulk SQL Data Seeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904692/ef-5-code-first-migration-bulk-sql-data-seeding)

Comment: The problem with the Seed method is that it runs every migration so you have to write sql that checks that data doesn't already exist before inserting. I think fixed data is better added using Sql("INSERT..") in the Up() method of a migration http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/preparing-databases

Comment: @Colin I couldn't disagree more when we're talking 2 million records.  Having to write an EXISTS statement at the top of your SQL to make it run in 10 minutes versus 10 hours seems like a pretty good trade off.

Comment: I'm going to experiment a bit more before confirming an answer. thanks for your help.

Comment: @wilso132. Sorry, my point wasn't clear. If you add the code to the Seed method then the code is run every time you subsequently update the database, and with 2,000,000 records that is likely to be expensive even with an EXISTS check. If you do the insert in a migration, the code only runs when you apply that migration. Put it in the correct migration and you know the records don't exist and you could consider leaving the exists checks out. You should also delete the records in the Down() - to ensure that it is still possible to tear all the way down, and then back up

Comment: You may find this blog relevant to this question - http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/