# C# - Entity Framework - Large seed data code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, poco

I'm going to create an initial table in my app to store all the cities/states of my country.
This is a relative large data set: 5k+ registries.

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904692/ef-5-code-first-migration-bulk-sql-data-seeding) enlightened to me a good way to do this, altough I think that leaving a sql file, that will be imported by the EF, in the open is a security flaw.

The file format is irrelevant: I can make it a XLS or a TXT if I want; instead of executing it as a SQL command as show in the post I can simply read it as a stream and generate the objects as shown in the tutorial of the next hiperlink.

Reading [this tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx) about data seed in code-first, I saw that the seed method will be executed in the *database initialization process* and the seed objects are generated in the seed method.

**My questions:**
About the seed methods, what is the best approach, the SQL-file approach or the object approach? 
I personally think that the object approach is more secure, but can be slower, possibility that generates my second question:
The seed method that is executed in the database initialization process, is executed **ONLY** when the DB is created? This is a little unclear to me.

Thanks.

Comment: The `Seed` method is executed when your db is created or when you run db migrations and it can get really slow if you have 5k entities to add. I would vote for an sql file as it will be much faster in terms of execution. When I've bumped into adding large object sets with EF, I had to commit changes to db after ~100 entities were added so that adding next entities would not take lots of time (though it was with EF 4)

Comment: You don't state what Database you are using.  But if you are using Sql Server you should consider using Bulk Copy or bcp.exe to load your database.  It is the fastest way to load a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Reference `System.Data` in your database project and add the NuGet package [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6/).
2. Insert your data in the seed method if you detect that it's not there yet:

   ```
   protected override void Seed(BulkEntities context)
   {
       if (!context.BulkItems.Any())
       {
           var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000)
                     .Select(s => new BulkItem
                     {
                         Name = s.ToString(),
                         Status = "asdf"
                     });

           context.BulkInsert(items, 1000);                
       }
   }
   ```

Inserting 100,000 items takes about 3 seconds over here.